# Autocomplete неточный поиск

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-directive

Реализовал поиск при помощи input+datalist, сначала была проблема с сафари, поборол при помощи полифила. 
В итоге все равно отказался так как проблемы в ИЕ, а так же из-за следующей проблемы.

Есть "улица. Горького (теремки)"
Если искать "горького", "теремки" то находит, но необходимо что бы так же находило и при воде "горького теремки", "горь теремк"  - такого плана запросы. Даже "горького теремки" не срабатывает из-за "()" так понимаю

С бека приходит нужные варианты, в даталисте они даже добавлялись в дом элементами но не выводились в браузере никак. В данный момент есть директива автокомплита + сервис который "ходит" на сервер и таскает нужные варианты. Проблемы как понимаю в самой директива, а именно в использовании фильтра. Подскажите как поправить и возможно ли это вообще.
Ссылка с директивой. Там сейчас для примера поиск по фильмам. Есть та же беда. Поиск по 2 словам из названия не дает результатов.  Как пример "All the Boys Love Mandy Lane" не находит по запросу "all lane" или "man lan"

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGNPrP)

```
<div class="autocomplete {{ attrs.class }}" id="{{ attrs.id }}">
          <input
            type="text"
            ng-model="searchParam"
            placeholder="{{ attrs.placeholder }}"
            class="{{ attrs.inputclass }}"
            id="{{ attrs.inputid }}"
            ng-required="{{ autocompleteRequired }}" />
          <ul ng-show="completing && (suggestions | filter:searchFilter).length > 0">
            <li
              suggestion
              ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions | filter:searchFilter | orderBy:'toString()' track by $index"
              index="{{ $index }}"
              val="{{ suggestion }}"
              ng-class="{ active: ($index === selectedIndex) }"
              ng-click="select(suggestion)"
              ng-bind-html="suggestion | highlight:searchParam"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Если там нельзя подпихнуть кастомный фильтр, то скорее всего Вы ничего не сделаете. Если всё таки, подпихнуть свой фильтр нельзя, то стоит сделать форк и написать такую возможность :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо изменить стандартную логику фильтрации `filter` на свою.

В строчке `ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions | filter:searchFilter | orderBy:\'toString()\' track by $index"\` вместо `filter:searchFilter` используйте собственный фильтр, который будет работать так, как вам надо.

Пример кастомного фильтра:

```
appAuto.filter('afilter',[function(){
 return function(array,searchStr){
 if(!searchStr)
  return array;
 let searchWords = searchStr.split(" ").map(s=>s.toLowerCase());//разбиваем на слова
 return array.filter(f=>{
  const lowerWord = f.toLowerCase();
  return searchWords.some(s=>{
    return lowerWord.indexOf(s)>-1;//если хоть одно слово совпало - выводим результат
  });
 });
}
}]);
```

Конечно, если нужна более сложная логика, например, отсортировать результаты по "весу" или что бы учитывался порядок слов, то это надо реализовывать отдельно.

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwNdyY).

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['autocomplete']);

// the service that retrieves some movie title from an url
app.factory('MovieRetriever', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
  var MovieRetriever = new Object();

  MovieRetriever.getmovies = function(i) {
    var moviedata = $q.defer();
    var movies;

    var someMovies = ["The Wolverine", "The Smurfs 2", "The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones", "Drinking Buddies", "All the Boys Love Mandy Lane", "The Act Of Killing", "Red 2", "Jobs", "Getaway", "Red Obsession", "2 Guns", "The World's End", "Planes", "Paranoia", "The To Do List", "Man of Steel"];

    var moreMovies = ["The Wolverine", "The Smurfs 2", "The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones", "Drinking Buddies", "All the Boys Love Mandy Lane", "The Act Of Killing", "Red 2", "Jobs", "Getaway", "Red Obsession", "2 Guns", "The World's End", "Planes", "Paranoia", "The To Do List", "Man of Steel", "The Way Way Back", "Before Midnight", "Only God Forgives", "I Give It a Year", "The Heat", "Pacific Rim", "Pacific Rim", "Kevin Hart: Let Me Explain", "A Hijacking", "Maniac", "After Earth", "The Purge", "Much Ado About Nothing", "Europa Report", "Stuck in Love", "We Steal Secrets: The Story Of Wikileaks", "The Croods", "This Is the End", "The Frozen Ground", "Turbo", "Blackfish", "Frances Ha", "Prince Avalanche", "The Attack", "Grown Ups 2", "White House Down", "Lovelace", "Girl Most Likely", "Parkland", "Passion", "Monsters University", "R.I.P.D.", "Byzantium", "The Conjuring", "The Internship"]

    if (i && i.indexOf('T') != -1)
      movies = moreMovies;
    else
      movies = moreMovies;

    $timeout(function() {
      moviedata.resolve(movies);
    }, 1000);

    return moviedata.promise
  }

  return MovieRetriever;
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MovieRetriever) {

  $scope.movies = MovieRetriever.getmovies("...");
  $scope.movies.then(function(data) {
    $scope.movies = data;
  });

  $scope.getmovies = function() {
    return $scope.movies;
  }

  $scope.doSomething = function(typedthings) {
    console.log("Do something like reload data with this: " + typedthings);
    $scope.newmovies = MovieRetriever.getmovies(typedthings);
    $scope.newmovies.then(function(data) {
      $scope.movies = data;
    });
  }

  $scope.doSomethingElse = function(suggestion) {
    console.log("Suggestion selected: " + suggestion);
  }

});



/* --- Made by justgoscha and licensed under MIT license --- */

var appAuto = angular.module('autocomplete', []);

appAuto.filter('afilter', [function() {
  return function(array, searchStr) {
    if (!searchStr)
      return array;
    let searchWords = searchStr.split(" ").map(s => s.toLowerCase());
    return array.filter(f => {
      const lowerWord = f.toLowerCase();
      return searchWords.some(s => {
        return lowerWord.indexOf(s) > -1;
      });
      return res;
    });
  }
}]);

appAuto.directive('autocomplete', function() {
  var index = -1;

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      searchParam: '=ngModel',
      suggestions: '=data',
      onType: '=onType',
      onSelect: '=onSelect',
      autocompleteRequired: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      // the index of the suggestions that's currently selected
      $scope.selectedIndex = -1;

      $scope.initLock = true;

      // set new index
      $scope.setIndex = function(i) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = parseInt(i);
      };

      this.setIndex = function(i) {
        $scope.setIndex(i);
        $scope.$apply();
      };

      $scope.getIndex = function(i) {
        return $scope.selectedIndex;
      };

      // watches if the parameter filter should be changed
      var watching = true;

      // autocompleting drop down on/off
      $scope.completing = false;

      // starts autocompleting on typing in something
      $scope.$watch('searchParam', function(newValue, oldValue) {

        if (oldValue === newValue || (!oldValue && $scope.initLock)) {
          return;
        }

        if (watching && typeof $scope.searchParam !== 'undefined' && $scope.searchParam !== null) {
          $scope.completing = true;
          $scope.searchFilter = $scope.searchParam;
          $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
        }

        // function thats passed to on-type attribute gets executed
        if ($scope.onType)
          $scope.onType($scope.searchParam);
      });

      // for hovering over suggestions
      this.preSelect = function(suggestion) {

        watching = false;

        // this line determines if it is shown
        // in the input field before it's selected:
        //$scope.searchParam = suggestion;

        $scope.$apply();
        watching = true;

      };

      $scope.preSelect = this.preSelect;

      this.preSelectOff = function() {
        watching = true;
      };

      $scope.preSelectOff = this.preSelectOff;

      // selecting a suggestion with RIGHT ARROW or ENTER
      $scope.select = function(suggestion) {
        if (suggestion) {
          $scope.searchParam = suggestion;
          $scope.searchFilter = suggestion;
          if ($scope.onSelect)
            $scope.onSelect(suggestion);
        }
        watching = false;
        $scope.completing = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          watching = true;
        }, 1000);
        $scope.setIndex(-1);
      };


    }],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        scope.initLock = false;
        scope.$apply();
      }, 250);

      var attr = '';

      // Default atts
      scope.attrs = {
        "placeholder": "start typing...",
        "class": "",
        "id": "",
        "inputclass": "",
        "inputid": ""
      };

      for (var a in attrs) {
        attr = a.replace('attr', '').toLowerCase();
        // add attribute overriding defaults
        // and preventing duplication
        if (a.indexOf('attr') === 0) {
          scope.attrs[attr] = attrs[a];
        }
      }

      if (attrs.clickActivation) {
        element[0].onclick = function(e) {
          if (!scope.searchParam) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              scope.completing = true;
              scope.$apply();
            }, 200);
          }
        };
      }

      var key = {
        left: 37,
        up: 38,
        right: 39,
        down: 40,
        enter: 13,
        esc: 27,
        tab: 9
      };

      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        switch (keycode) {
          case key.esc:
            // disable suggestions on escape
            scope.select();
            scope.setIndex(-1);
            scope.$apply();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }, true);

      document.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
        // disable suggestions on blur
        // we do a timeout to prevent hiding it before a click event is registered
        setTimeout(function() {
          scope.select();
          scope.setIndex(-1);
          scope.$apply();
        }, 150);
      }, true);

      element[0].addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        var l = angular.element(this).find('li').length;

        // this allows submitting forms by pressing Enter in the autocompleted field
        if (!scope.completing || l == 0) return;

        // implementation of the up and down movement in the list of suggestions
        switch (keycode) {
          case key.up:

            index = scope.getIndex() - 1;
            if (index < -1) {
              index = l - 1;
            } else if (index >= l) {
              index = -1;
              scope.setIndex(index);
              scope.preSelectOff();
              break;
            }
            scope.setIndex(index);

            if (index !== -1)
              scope.preSelect(angular.element(angular.element(this).find('li')[index]).text());

            scope.$apply();

            break;
          case key.down:
            index = scope.getIndex() + 1;
            if (index < -1) {
              index = l - 1;
            } else if (index >= l) {
              index = -1;
              scope.setIndex(index);
              scope.preSelectOff();
              scope.$apply();
              break;
            }
            scope.setIndex(index);

            if (index !== -1)
              scope.preSelect(angular.element(angular.element(this).find('li')[index]).text());

            break;
          case key.left:
            break;
          case key.right:
          case key.enter:
          case key.tab:

            index = scope.getIndex();
            // scope.preSelectOff();
            if (index !== -1) {
              scope.select(angular.element(angular.element(this).find('li')[index]).text());
              if (keycode == key.enter) {
                e.preventDefault();
              }
            } else {
              if (keycode == key.enter) {
                scope.select();
              }
            }
            scope.setIndex(-1);
            scope.$apply();

            break;
          case key.esc:
            // disable suggestions on escape
            scope.select();
            scope.setIndex(-1);
            scope.$apply();
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
          default:
            return;
        }

      });
    },
    template: '\
        <div class="autocomplete {{ attrs.class }}" id="{{ attrs.id }}">\
          <input\
            type="text"\
            ng-model="searchParam"\
            placeholder="{{ attrs.placeholder }}"\
            class="{{ attrs.inputclass }}"\
            id="{{ attrs.inputid }}"\
            ng-required="{{ autocompleteRequired }}" />\
          <ul ng-show="completing && (suggestions | afilter:searchFilter).length > 0">\
            <li\
              suggestion\
              ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions | afilter: searchFilter | orderBy:\'toString()\' track by $index"\
              index="{{ $index }}"\
              val="{{ suggestion }}"\
              ng-class="{ active: ($index === selectedIndex) }"\
              ng-click="select(suggestion)"\
              ng-bind-html="suggestion | highlight:searchParam"></li>\
          </ul>\
        </div>'
  };
});

appAuto.filter('highlight', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(input, searchParam) {
    if (typeof input === 'function') return '';
    if (searchParam) {
      var words = '(' +
        searchParam.split(/\ /).join(' |') + '|' +
        searchParam.split(/\ /).join('|') +
        ')',
        exp = new RegExp(words, 'gi');
      if (words.length) {
        input = input.replace(exp, "<span class=\"highlight\">$1</span>");
      }
    }
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
  };
}]);

appAuto.directive('suggestion', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^autocomplete', // ^look for controller on parents element
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, autoCtrl) {
      element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
        autoCtrl.preSelect(attrs.val);
        autoCtrl.setIndex(attrs.index);
      });

      element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
        autoCtrl.preSelectOff();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
@font-face {
  /* Entypo pictograms by Daniel Bruce — www.entypo.com */
  font-family: 'Entypo';
  src: url('../assets/entypo.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../assets/entypo.eot') format('eot');
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2b7;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #b15;
  transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: inherit;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}


/* taken from bootstrap */

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.hide-text {
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.input-block-level {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

img {
  /* Responsive images (ensure images don't scale beyond their parents) */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */
  width: auto\9;
  /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */
  height: auto;
  /* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching */
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Generic classes */

.hide {
  /* Hide stuff without resorting to display:none; */
  visibility: hidden !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  line-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.hide:after {
  /* Hide stuff without resorting to display:none; */
  visibility: hidden !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  line-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background: url('../sprinkles.png') repeat;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 30em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  padding: 0.7em 1em 0.5em 2em;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #333;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
}

.thin {
  font-weight: 100;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 4em;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #44ba54;
  text-align: center;
}

footer a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #b15;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* AUTOCOMPLETE */

.autocomplete {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.autocomplete input {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.autocomplete ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  z-index: 1;
}

.autocomplete li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.autocomplete li.active {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4bf;
}

.autocomplete .highlight {
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

.autocomplete li.active .highlight {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>


</head>

<body>

  <header>

  </header>


  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="main">

      <autocomplete ng-model="result" attr-placeholder="type to search movies..." click-activation="true" data="movies" on-type="doSomething" on-select="doSomethingElse"></autocomplete>
      <br>

    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: да, пожалуйста, если не сложно объясните. не могу разобраться с фильтрами нормально

Comment: ага, все таки разбивать на слова, тоже так думал, но надеялся что есть какой то вариант более гуманный что ли)  спасибо. буду пробовать.

Comment: Конечно, можно попробовать использовать регулярные выражения в кастомном фильтре, но это чревато... Придется экранировать все спец-символы, что не легко. Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте его верным.

Comment: спасибо, а как можно ужесточить данный поиск что бы выводило только те где совпал 2 слова? если их введено 2. потому что получается выводит все результаты где хотя бы 1 из слов, а мне нужно как раз искать по 2м словам что бы если вводиться 2 слова то отсекались лишние результаты. второе слово как бы уточняющее при необходимости.

Comment: у меня просто поиск по улицам, и есть к примеру некая улица Жукова коих 70шт в городе. а в "( )" указаны районы где эти улицы. получается что если человек вводит "жукова *район*" то все равно получает весь список улиц жукова так как в поиске присутствует слово "жукова".

Comment: Вам необходимо соответствующим образом модифицировать код `afilter` фильтра. Попробуйте заменить `some` на `every`.